# Format a cell to show longer duration as hhhh:mm:ss and sub-1min durations as ss. with decimals

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working with a mixture of very long and very short durations, of which the short durations need to be displayed very accurately. If I format the cells in the *Time* column as 'Duration', then the results are shown as in the table below.

However, the result of `00:15:00 / 20 * 16.8` is `2.68sec` and I'm very interested in those decimals for all *Time* values under 1 minute. *Custom Date and Time* formatting does not offer an option for this and I haven't been able to create a *Custom Number* format à la `[>60]hh:mm:ss;...` successfully. Can this be achieved in a single cell or do I need to have one formatted for each?

| Origin | Time |
| --- | --- |
| `00:15:00 / 20 * 16.8` | 00:00:03 |
| `31250:00:00 / 2 / 16.8` | 930:03:34 |

Comment: I would like to ask how did you convert `00:15:00 / 20 * 16.8` to `2.68sec`? Also it would be best if you can provide a dummy sheet to work on with your desired output.

Comment: This might help: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/91997/conditional-number-format-whole-number-percentage-based-on-the-value-in-anoth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your idea **[>60]hh:mm:ss;...** is correct. You just need to convert 60 seconds to a fraction of a day:

```
1 minute = 1/24/60 days = 0.00069444...
```

So the format you need to enter in custom number format is

```
[<.00069444]ss.00;[h]:mm:ss
```

[image]

There is an edge case where if you have a value like 00:00:59.995 it will display as 00.00 so you could avoid that by adding minutes to the format:

```
[<.00069444]m:ss.00;[h]:mm:ss
```

so it will display as 1:00.00 or by changing the constant slightly to 0.000694386574

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround to do something similar using multiple columns:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15g9Tv8Uv1nJ0TnjZszQyzvHFaOMMmqX5c2OpMAyQGkc/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Credit to DanCue for the idea